# Updating UI Thread from TimerCallback Function Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8

a little stumped here.

I have a TimerCallback that fires every 10 seconds which contains Geopoints to put on a map. I try to add these to the map from within the timer callback function, however since it is in a different thread, I am unable to do this. I receive the following errors:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary.
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

How would can I circumvent this? I thought that maybe added a NotifyCollectionChanged listener would work, however I am still having the same problem. Code is shown below.

```
    private ObservableCollection<Bus> _busList;
    private Timer _timer = null;
    public ItemViewModel route;

    public ObservableCollection<Bus> BusList
    {
        get { return _busList; }
        set { _busList = value; }
    }
    //public LocationManager locMan = LocationManager.Instance;
    // Constructor
    public DetailsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    // When page is navigated to set data context to selected item in list
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        route = null;
        if (DataContext == null)
        {
            string selectedIndex = "";
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out selectedIndex))
            {
                int index = int.Parse(selectedIndex);
                DataContext = App.ViewModel.Items[index];
                route = App.ViewModel.Items[index];
                if (_timer == null)
                {
                    TimerCallback tcb = obtainJSON;
                    _timer = new Timer(tcb, route.RouteID, 0, 10000);
                }
                else
                {
                    _timer.Change(0, 10000);
                }
                if (BusList == null)
                {
                    BusList = new ObservableCollection<Bus>();
                }
                else
                {
                    BusList.Clear();
                }
                BusList.CollectionChanged += HandleBusAdded;
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandleBusAdded(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Everything was cleared");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Bus item in e.NewItems)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(item.vehicleID);
                Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
                polygon.Points.Add(new Point(0, 0));
                polygon.Points.Add(new Point(0, 75));
                polygon.Points.Add(new Point(25, 0));
                polygon.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

                // Create a MapOverlay and add marker
                MapOverlay overlay = new MapOverlay();
                overlay.Content = polygon;
                overlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(item.lat, item.lng);
                overlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.0, 1.0);
                MapLayer mapLayer = new MapLayer();
                mapLayer.Add(overlay);
                //mapView.Layers.Add(mapLayer);

                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    mapView.Layers.Add(mapLayer);
                });
            }
        }

    }

    public void obtainJSON(Object stateInfo)
    {

        string url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx" + stateInfo.ToString();
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Decrypt);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
    }

    public void Decrypt(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BusList.Count > 0)
        {
            BusList.Clear();
        }
        if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
        {
            var temp = new List<string>();
            string[] buses = e.Result.Split('\n');
            foreach (string bus in buses)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bus) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(bus))
                {
                    temp.Add(bus);
                }
            }
            foreach (string item in temp)
            {
                string[] busInfo = item.Split(',');
                Bus newBus = new Bus(busInfo[0], busInfo[1], busInfo[2]);
                BusList.Add(newBus);

            }

            // This is where I initially tried
            /*Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
            polygon.Points.Add(new Point(0, 0));
            polygon.Points.Add(new Point(0, 75));
            polygon.Points.Add(new Point(25, 0));
            polygon.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

            // Enable marker to be tapped for location information
            // polygon.Tag = new GeoCoordinate(BusList[0].lat, BusList[0].lng);

            // Create a MapOverlay and add marker
            MapOverlay overlay = new MapOverlay();
            overlay.Content = polygon;
            overlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(BusList[0].lat, BusList[0].lng);
            overlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.0, 1.0);
            MapLayer mapLayer = new MapLayer();
            mapLayer.Add(overlay);

            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                mapView.Layers.Add(mapLayer);
            });*/
            Debug.WriteLine("Present buses " + BusList[0].vehicleID + ", " + BusList[1].vehicleID);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to wrap what happens in your `obtainJSON` method in an anonymous function that is dispatched back to the UI thread:

```
public void obtainJSON(Object stateInfo)
{    
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { 
        string url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx" + stateInfo.ToString();
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Decrypt);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
    });    
}
```

This will mean that everything (both making the web request and processing the response as `WebClient` now executes it's callback on the thread it was called from) happens on the UI thread so you're not updating objects that are bound to the UI thread from a different thread.

You could also try using a `DispatcherTimer` rather than the threading one.

You should also take care to handle poor network conditions where a request will timeout after more than 10 seconds and you could end up with multiple requests running - which may or may not be an issue for you.